# Retrieving the data from firebase into array

Tags: angular, typescript, web

I need to display all the users that were created in Firebase.

I tried to make a list of observable but it didn't show anything

```
export class UsersListComponent implements OnInit {
  users: Observable<any[]> ;

  constructor(db2: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.users = db2.list('/users').valueChanges();

          }
```

and here is my HTML

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users | async">
     {{ user | json }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I don't get anything shown on the screen here is my firebase structure

Firebase structure

[image]

Comment: what do you see when you console.log(this.users)

Comment: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
operator: MapOperator {project: ƒ, thisArg: undefined}
source: Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
_isScalar: false
__proto__: Object         @Sajeetharan  this is what i get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to retrieve the users through a service, create an angular service

```
export class UserService {

  usertList: AngularFireList<any>;

  constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { }

  getUsers() {
    return this.userList= this.db.list('users');
  }
}
```

and in component,

```
constructor(
    private userService: UserService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().snapshotChanges().subscribe(
      item => {
        this.userList= [];
        item.forEach(
          element => {
            const x = element.payload.toJSON();
            x['$key'] = element.key;
            this.userList.push(x as User);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: I don't know why but the item is empty therefor the foreach loop was never executed    @Sajeethran